# Want decimal result Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, decimal, amazon-redshift

I am trying to calculate the average ice creams a kid will have during summer. 
I want the result to have 2 decimals. 
Query:

```
Select day, (sum(ice_cream_cones) *1.0)/(select count(kids)) 
From t1 Group by 1
```

The result I get is something like 1.0003. I only want 2 decimal points.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL. There are unbalance parentheses.

Comment: @GMB it is a made up query to resemble the real one. Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with round

```
Select day, round((sum(ice_cream_cones) *1.0)/(select count(kids) ), 2)
From t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source data are integers...

```
SUM(ice_cream_cones) * 100 / COUNT(kids) / 100.0
```

Or, cast your existing calculation to a decimal?

```
CAST(<calc> AS DECIMAL(8,2))
```